# Routing in codeigniter :\

Tags: codeigniter, url, routes

I'm really stuck in doing routes for my app and I find rooting in CI very confusing
so what I have is some pages of people in each country, and you get to that page by selecting a country in a drop list in the home page 
I manage to pass data using POST method, but the problem is I can't access these pages directly by a url, because their main controller do access to db and generate them 
so for now all my pages have this url

```
www.site.com/country
```

country is a controler

but i want is to look like this:

```
www.site.com/name-of-country/name-of-person
```

any idea how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These answers don't give enough info, and the accepted answer is just terrible...

The best way to handle this would be to set up your routing to do the following (if you want to control the countries that the users are able to use:

put this in your routes file:

```
foreach(array('country1', 'country2') as $country) { // array with allowed countries
  $routes[$country.'/(:any)'] = "country/view/{$country}/$1";
  $routes[$country] = "country/view/{$country}";
}
```

what this does is takes your array of allowed countries and then creates a routing rule for each country, so if a user goes to `http://example.com/japan/naruto`, it routes to the url `http://example.com/country/view/japan/naruto`. This is assuming that 'japan' is in your 'allowed countries' array.

The second one simply routes the url `http://example.com/japan` to `http://example.com/country/view/japan`

into your controller `country.php`:

```
class Country extends CI_Controller {
  function view($country, $username = false) { // $username=false allows you to show just a 'country' page if you want to
    if ($username) {
      $this->load->view('users_view', array('country' => $country, 'username' => $username));
    } else {
     $this->load->view('countries_view', array('country' => $country)) 
    }
  }
}
```

what I have done here is enabled you to create a page just for the country that is displayed which loads the `countries_view.php` out of your views folder, or you can view the page for the user, which loads the `users_view.php` page.

Comment: is this work if i have all countries of all the world? I have counties names stored in database whenever i activate one country it should be visible to users

Comment: Yes, you'd need to put them into an array and run the foreach() on that array.

Comment: So you would rather hand-maintain an array of countries in your routes file, than to have the database (which already contains the same information) do your access control for you? Now you've not only violated the DRY (Don't Repeat Yourself) principle and the driving principles behind the MVC architecture on which CodeIgniter is built, but you've made a lot more work for yourself.

Comment: The purpose of the answer is to demonstrate how to do this. the array could easily be countries drawn from the database. I also find your downvote to be completely unjustified as my answer was not wrong. In answering questions your job is not to do all of the work for somebody, more of a 'show them how' and they adjust the answer to suit their needs. I assume that the OP has some knowledge of querying a database and creating an array out of the resulting data, otherwise creating a database driven site probably isn't a wise choice...

Comment: The OP asked how to use the routes file to redirect URLs based on dynamic data, presumably in either a database or some other data model (or at least it should be). Your answer tells him exactly how to do this. Trouble is, you are both abusing the routes file. It's not intended as a gatekeeper for dynamic data, and it is certainly not intended to interact with databases. I told him the proper way to parse URLs--that is, by using controller arguments--and you called that "just terrible". I downvoted your answer because it perpetuates bad practices.

Comment: The point of me saying your answer was terrible is that it did not say how to get from what would have had to be the url `http://example.com/country/person` to `http://example.com/controller/method/country/person` which is what my example does. It then shows how to access the data in the controller. How this perpetuates bad practices is beyond me, it's very similar to what you did but with more secure routing. Of course  a different way would be to route any input to the method but this brings up issues in itself.

Comment: Some MVC bad practices exemplified here: Using the routes file rather than a controller for access control; querying the database from the routes file; implementing control structures in the routes file.

Comment: Regardless of your opinions, the fact is that your answer did not answer the question the OP had asked. While I agree that a better method would be to do the query in the controller, using `htaccess` to provide exceptions and then `$route['(exception)/(:any)'] = '$1'` and `$route[(:any)/(:any)] = 'country/view/$1/$2'` to pass the variables, I provided my answer as an alternative which would enable routing to be more controlled, which is what the OP wanted and provided more information than the other two posts.

Answer (score 3):

Controllers in CI can take arguments, just like regular functions. Those arguments are passed as URL segments. So if you want to type:

```
www.site.com/name-of-country/name-of-person
```

just write your function like this:

```
function Country($name_of_country, $name_of_person) { ... }
```

To redirect from postdata, try this:

```
function Country($name_of_country, $name_of_person) {
  if ($this->input->post('country') {
    redirect('/country/' . $this->input->post('country'));
  }
}
```

For more information, review the [official documentation on routing](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html).

Comment: thanks thats great, but how would i generate this url if the user shoos to go throw home page then get to the persons page, how to show that in url?

Comment: If you want to use a form to do this, you can add a condition to your Country controller which looks for postdata and redirects as necessary.

Comment: yes you are right it can be done by redirecting, i just figure that out, thank you for your help :)

Answer (score 2):

You could also set this up in the routes.php file by using some regex. It depends on how your application is setup and how controlled your routes are. For instance, if you did this:

```
$route['(:any)/(:any)'] = 'country';
```

You'd probably match more than you wanted. You could use more specific regex instead of something generic like that, or... you could change the URL structure a bit:

```
$route['country/(:any)/(:any)'] = 'country/index/$1/$2';
```

Then you can set up that logic in the routes file where it belongs. If you have a routes file, you should use instead of trying to do routing through a controller as well.